# delaying function before it launches not working

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I'm trying to delay a function that I have in a jquery script from launching.  I put in a settimeout but it isn't taking for some reason, it breaks the rest of the script.  Thanks in advance for any help I can get on this.

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#fullscreen_launch").click(function () {
            $("#fullscreen").animate({
                height: '100%',
                top: '0px',
            }, 950, setTimeout(function () {
                $('#fullscreen').load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html');
            }, 2000);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last parameter to `animate` is a callback.  `setTimeout` doesn't return a function, it returns a timeoutID (used for `clearTimeout`).  You need to pass a function to `animate`.

```
$(function () {
    $("#fullscreen_launch").click(function () {
        $("#fullscreen").animate({
            height: '100%',
            top: '0px',
        }, 950, function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#fullscreen').load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html');
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @loriensleafs That wasn't the question, was it?

Comment: @loriensleafs: Try using different values for `height` and `top`.

Comment: yea it actually does work, thanks for figuring that out for me

Answer (score 1):

I got your code working, it's located here: http://jsfiddle.net/VEXfJ/7/

A good way to step through your code is to add alert statements.

```
$(function()
{
    $("#fullscreen_launch").click(function()
    {
        alert("Clicked");

        $("#fullscreen").animate(
        {
            top: 0,
            height: 'toggle'
        }, 5000, function()
        {

            alert("animate complete");

            setTimeout(function()
            {
                alert("timeout");
                $('#fullscreen').load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html');
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: `alert` issn't the best debugging tool, `console` is a lot better.

Comment: I never said it was the 'best', simply that is is a good way to step through code. Personally, I prefer alerts to the console. Just a matter of preference.

Comment: Due to the blocking nature of alert, it really issn't suited to debug code where knowing when things happen is important.